# Given that $0<a<b$, can I conclude the convergence or divergence of the sequence $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$?

Tags: calculus

If $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$ for $0<a<b$, we have that $b_n\to\infty$ and $a_n\to\infty$ when  $n\to\infty$, then 
$$\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n},$$
is monotone, There exist a bound to show the convergence?

Comment: You mention that $b_n\rightarrow\infty$, but $b_n$ doesn't show up in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Note that:
$$
\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} \geq \sqrt[n]{0^n+b^n} = b
$$
and:
$$
\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{b^n+b^n} = \sqrt[n]{2b^n} = \sqrt[n]{2} \cdot b
$$
and observe that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[n]{2} \cdot b) = b
$$

Answer (score 2):

First: It's wrong in general that you have  $a_n\to\infty$ or $b_n \to \infty$.

If $0 < a < b < 1$ you have $a_n \to 0$ and so $b_n$.

To solve your problem: $$\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} = \sqrt[n]{b^n\left(\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n+1\right)} = b\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n+1}$$

and because

$$ b \le b\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n+1} < b\left(\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n+1\right)$$

you get

$$\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} \to b$$